# Could not retrieve data from URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

When I add a link from my news-blog into Facebook, the post no longer contains images or metadata from the post.

I noticed this occurring about 4 weeks ago and running it through de-bugger 2-10 times would eventually return a fix however in the last few days it no longer seems to help.

For example, when running this post through the debugger: http://beyondgoinglong.co.uk/?p=2870

It returns the following results:

- Response code:200
- Can't  download: Could not retrieve data from URL

My website is here http://beyondgoinglong.co.uk/

I do not have this problem of scraping data on other sites such as Google+.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have some sort of rule in your server configuration file that is serving empty content to the Facebook crawler. Check your `.htaccess` file and server logs to see what is going on here.

Once you fix this, you'll most likely still have issues. The Facebook parser is pretty strict and you have some [major problems with your XHTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fbeyondgoinglong.co.uk%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).